# IOS: didSelectRowAtIndexPath select multiple cells while selecting single cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView populated with 30+ UITableviewCells.

The problem I am facing is that, when selecting a row and changing the accessoryType of the cell, the eleventh row from that row also gets modified.

I have tried printing the `[indexPath row]` value, but it is showing only the row that was selected and not another one.

I am using the following code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

.
.
.
}
```

Please help me how to overcome this issue

Comment: Can you please show the code that sets & changes the `accessoryType` of the cell ?

Comment: it is the issue of reusable cell.

Comment: in prepare for reuse of your cell change accessoryType to none

Comment: how to remove this issue i updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need keep track of selected cells, you can do this using NSMutableDictionary as key use the IndexPath.row and as value a String, so in your DidSelectRow modify the dictionary setting the value for the Row = "Selected" and in your CellForRow method check if Dictionary[indexPath.row] == "Selected" then put your accessory by default remove it

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property NSMutableDictionary * dict;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    if([((NSString*)[_dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)indexPath.row]]) isEqualToString: @"Selected"])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    return cell;
}
```

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * value = (NSString*)[_dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)indexPath.row]];

    if ([value isEqualToString:@"Selected"]){
        [_dict setValue:@"UnSelected" forKey:value];
    }else{
        [_dict setValue:@"Selected" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)indexPath.row]];
    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath,[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[value integerValue] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks a ton i will implement this code to my code i am unable to upvote or accept this answer due to low rating

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap my answer was updated again, now is working as should, I think that you can accept the answer at least, best regards!

Comment: @ekashking you can use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`method also,  check my updated answer,